# Create dummy variable for categorical variabls

Tags: julia, categorical-data, dummy-variable

Is there a function/ way to generate dummy variable in `Julia` similar to `R`? I know I can use `RCall` package and create the dummy variable then use `@rget` but I'm looking for an alternative in Julia.

```
x1=string.([2 ,1 ,2,  1, 2 ,1 ,1 ,3, 2, 2])
x2=string.([1 ,1 ,3, 2, 2, 2 ,1 ,2,  1, 2])
R"""
library(qdapTools)
df = data.frame(catg1 = $x1, catg2= $x2)
dum_var=cbind(mtabulate(df$catg1), mtabulate(df$catg2))
"""
```

Comment: I have closed the question as it seems to me it is exactly the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64565276/julia-dataframes-how-to-do-one-hot-encoding. If there is something else you would need please comment.